# How to make hardcoded virtual record in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In some models (ex: Language), I want to use stub records (ex: "none") with hardcoded id and columns in model class. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The `db/seeds.rb` file sounds like a good fit for you.

Here's a good Railscast on it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much prefer fixtures for that, but people also seem to like Factories for that (i tend to use Factory Girl for my tests).

So, you can quite easily do that in both ways.